# How to implement the large text accessibility to uilabel attributed without losing the font

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

i have been trying to implement the large text accessibility for attributed text in a label. I have tried a lot of research and found the following way

```
   attributedTextLabel.attributedText = viewModel.attributedString
    // accessibility
    attributedTextLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
    if let accessibilityLabel = viewModel.accessibilityLabel {
        attributedTextLabel.accessibilityLabel = accessibilityLabel
        attributedTextLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        attributedTextLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }
```

But the issue with this approach is that iam loosing the font i have set for the attributed text which consists of multiple fonts in the format of :-

Bold: Simple text

Guys, is there any way to implement large text accessibility for uilabel dynamic text retaining the font of the attributed text. Thanks in advance